# Randomize and compare matrices in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, random

I have two matrices (1 and 2) which I multiply, resulting in the concordance matrix (c).

I need to randomize one of theses matrices 1000 times and them compare the number of times the value of these concordance matrices were higher than the first comparation.

```
# Exemple:
 mat1 <- matrix(rbinom(222, 1, 0.5),nrow=74,ncol=3) # habitat

 mat2 <- matrix(rbinom(592, 1, 0.5),nrow=74,ncol=8) # modular

 tmat1 <- t(mat1)

 # Multipying the tranposed matrix 1 by matrix 2:

 c <- tmat1%*%mat2 # concordance matrix c

 resu <- matrix(NA,nrow=3,ncol=8) # creating the matrix to fill with the results of values higher than c

  for(r in 1:1000) {

mat3 <- apply(mat1,1,sample) # randomizing matrix 1, maintaining the number of intercations by nodes

cc <- mat3%*%mat2 # multiplying these matrices 

for (i in 1:dim(c)[1]){ # rows

 for(j in 1:dim(c)[2]){ # columns

   if(cc[i]>=c[j]){ #  

   resu[i,j] <- sum(cc[i]>=c[j]) # filling the matrix with the number of times cc was higher then c

   } 

 }

}

}
```

But the result is wrong: it is resulting in a matrix with correct number of rows (3) and columns (8) but all fill out by 1.

Each element has to be a different number of times the concordance was higher in cc[i] than c[j].

Any thoughts, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a smaller version and work through what you are trying to do. I am setting a random seed so you will get the same results:

```
set.seed(42)
mat1 <- matrix(rbinom(75, 1, 0.5), nrow=25, ncol=3)
mat2 <- matrix(rbinom(200, 1, 0.5), nrow=25, ncol=8)
tmat1 <- t(mat1)
c <- tmat1 %*% mat2
c
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]   10   11   10    7   10    9    5    6
# [2,]    9   11   11    7    8    7    4    8
# [3,]    5    7    8    6    7    4    4    7
```

Now you want a version of `mat1` with the values in each row shuffled. Then you want to know how many values are larger in the second matrix:

```
mat3 <- apply(mat1, 1, sample)
cc <- mat3 %*% mat2
cc
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    7   10   12    7   10    8    5    8
# [2,]    9    8    7    5    6    5    3    5
# [3,]    8   11   10    8    9    7    5    8
cc > c
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
sum(cc > c)
# [1] 10
```

Now create a function that handles this step:

```
matrand <- function(mat1, mat2, prod) {
    mat3 <- apply(mat1, 1, sample)
     cc <- mat3 %*% mat2
     cc > prod
}
```

Finally run the function as many times as you want:

```
results <- replicate(10, matrand(mat1=mat1, mat2=mat2, prod=c))
apply(results, 1:2, sum)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    1    1    4    2    0    1    3    4
# [2,]    4    3    1    1    6    4    6    2
# [3,]    8    8    9    5    6    9    3    5
```

The object `results` is a 3x8x10 array. The above matrix is the number of times `cc` was higher for that cell over the 10 replications.

Comment: Thank you! I still learning how to use here and R. For the results I need to see the number of times the cc had a higher value than c: for the element [1,1] how many times randomize cc had higher value than the concordance matrix c, and go on to every combination of elements of my resltant concordance matrix after the randomization of cc. I gonna try to work with the function you suggest to see if I can adapt to do this.

Comment: For that you will probably want to save the whole matrix (cc > pro) rather than just the sum. I've modified the answer to save all of the logical matrices in a single array.

Comment: Yes, it worked @dcarlson! But there is a thing... in my case it is important in the randomization to mantain the same value of sum of the rows and only randomize the labels columns. I don't know why exactly, but when using the _apply_ with the tranposed _mat1_ and tranposing after the _mat3_ works. The rows mantain the total number but with different distribution on the columns. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the package `purrr` and use the map and reduce concept

```
library(purrr)
mat1 <- matrix(rbinom(222, 1, 0.5),nrow=74,ncol=3) # habitat

mat2 <- matrix(rbinom(592, 1, 0.5),nrow=74,ncol=8) # modular

tmat1 <- t(mat1)

# Multipying the tranposed matrix 1 by matrix 2:

c <- tmat1%*%mat2
mat3 <- apply(mat1,1,sample)
cc<-mat3 %*% mat2
map(1:1000, ~apply(mat1,1,sample)) %>% #sample 1000 matrices
  map(~`%*%`(.,mat2)) %>% # multiply them with mat2
  map(~`>`(., c)) %>% #check for each result which element is greather the first result c
  reduce(`+`) # use the fact that TRUE -> 1 and just sum all the comparison matrices
```

R handles all the elementwise operations for under the hood so this should be all that you need.

Comment: Thank you, Bertil Baron and @Dharman ! This also worked, but as using the other suggestion, in my case it is important for the randomization to mantain the same value of the rows sum and only randomize the labels columns. I don't know why exactly, but when using the _apply_ with the tranposed _mat1_ and tranposing after this the _mat3_ works in the way I need here. The rows mantain the total number but with different distribution on the columns. Thank you very much!!